# The method scrollTo(String) is undefined for the type AndroidDriver in appium

Tags: java, testing, appium, scrollto

i am beginner to appium testing tool,I tried  scroll to text  program,But it was getting the following error "The method scrollTo(String) is undefined for the type AndroidDriver",

From there i learned 'scrollTo" method is depreciated.. is there any solution  for the below code i tried

```
package Android;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ScrollingToText {

     AndroidDriver driver;

     @BeforeTest
     public void setUp() throws Exception {
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "0123456789ABCDEF");
      capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
      capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
      capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.appium.android.apis");
      capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","io.appium.android.apis.ApiDemos");
      driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }

     @Test
     public void ScrollToText() throws InterruptedException {
      //Scroll till element which contains "Views" text If It Is not visible on screen.
     driver.scrollTo("Views");
      // Click on Views/.
      driver.findElement(By.name("Views")).click();
      System.out.println("Scrolling has been started to find text -> Tabs.");
      // Scroll till element which contains Tabs text.
     driver.scrollTo("Tabs");
      System.out.println("Tabs text has been found and now clicking on It.");
      // Click on Tabs.
      driver.findElement(By.name("Tabs")).click();
     }

     @AfterTest
     public void End() {
      driver.quit();
     }
    }
```

Comment: what version of appium java client are you using?

Comment: I tried both -->1.java-client-5.0.0-BETA4  and    2.java-client-4.0.0

Comment: This method must help you - https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidSearchingTest.java#L60

Comment: replaced the driver.scrollTo("Views"); with driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Views").click(); but still it doesn't working? please help with the above code if it requires any other changes?

Comment: have shared an answer on how to use the same.

Comment: getting the following error  Type mismatch: cannot convert from WebElement to MobileElement

Comment: From https://discuss.appium.io/t/difference-between-webelement-mobileelement-androidelement-and-ioselement/5254/3 one of contributor's words - *"Basically, using WebElement will let you use all the normal Selenium commands. MobileElement is appium's element which subclasses WebElement and adds appium-specific features (like being able to perform Touch Gestures).
AndroidElement and IOSElement implement MobileElement and add OS-specific features. Like on Android you can use findByUIAutomator and on iOS you can use findByUIAutomation"*

Answer (score 0):

According to one of the comments from [github/appium #421](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/421)

You should be able to find and scroll to a `MobileElement` using

```
MobileElement radioGroup = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()"
        + ".resourceId(\"android:id/list\")).scrollIntoView("
        + "new UiSelector().text(\"Radio Group\"));");
```

Also to scroll to a sub-element in a list, you can use -

```
MobileElement radioGroup = list
        .findElement(MobileBy
                .AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView("
                + "new UiSelector().text(\"Radio Group\"));"));
```

where you can replace the `anroid:id/list` and text `Radio Group` with the required element's values.

**Source** - [`findScrollabe()`](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidSearchingTest.java#L60) and [`scrollingToSubElement()`](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidElementTest.java#L70)

***Edit*** - For anyone seeking help with iOS, [`IOSScrollingSearchingTest`](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSScrollingSearchingTest.java) should be helpful to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code it will work for me.

```
private String str = "Select";

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+str+"\").instance(0))");
```